# How to use SBT with multiple sub project web applications?

Tags: scala, web-applications, sbt

I am building some web applications using SBT to handle my dependencies. The web apps are  using some common libraries and will likely end up running in the same web container. I would like to use a project setup where each of these web applications are sub-projects and all of them are started when I run `container:start` in SBT. Are there any guides how to set this up? Is there a better way to organize my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xsbt-webplugin has an example in [src/sbt-test/webapp-common/multi-container](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/master/src/sbt-test/webapp-common/multi-container/).

Comment: This link is no longer valid due to changes for the 1.0 version of that plugin.  That example can now be found here: https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/0.9/src/sbt-test/webapp-common/multi-container/project/Build.scala