# How to structure SBT projects with both jars and wars?

Tags: scala, sbt, vs-web-application-project

I previously asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9348524/355499) about how to use SBT with multiple sub project web applications. This worked excellent, now however I am trying to create a sub project that should NOT be a webapp, but which the other web app projects will depend on (common models etc etc). Is there a way to set up this sub project in along with the other web application sub projects OR should I just create a separate project alltogehter that creates a jar and have my webapps have it as a library dependency?

Currently I have the code for the non webapp project in as a subproject and the other sub projects depend on it, i.e.

```
 lazy val admin = Project("admin", file("admin")) dependsOn(common) settings(webappSettings :_*)
                                                  // ^^^^ defines the dependency
 ... other project definitions                     

 lazy val common = Project("common", file("common"))
```

This works, but when I package the applications I get a `common.war`.

I should probably also mention that the common project does contain some web related code that depend on Lift, but I want it to be packaged as a jar and not a war... Oh, and the webapp wars seem to  include the actual classes into the generated war from the common project.

So how should I:

- Create a `common` project which contain web related code (will for instance need to run tests that uses jetty), but is compiled into a jar?
- Include the `common` project in my web application projects?
- Can/should the `common` project be included as a sub project along with my web applications?

Comment: Most examples I have seen have the settings as the last argument to the `Project` constructor and the `dependsOn` as the last thing, like [this example](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Full-Configuration-Example). Have you tried that? I don't know why what you have would give the behaviour you describe, particularly getting a war for the "common" project. I have a project [here](https://github.com/tekul/connect/blob/master/project/build.scala) which builds both a jar and a war which you might want to look at.